# IndexError: list index out of range while using If statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am unable to understand why this error is coming.
In case i am not using if statement , the error is gone.

Here is my code:

```
def merge_the_tools(string, k):
    # your code goes here
    nlist=[]
    nlistf=[]
    lin = list(string)
    for i in range(int(len(lin)/k)):
        nlist.append(lin[k*i:(k*i+k)])


    for i in nlist:
        for j in i:
            count=0
            for m in range(k):
                if i[m]==j:
                    count=count+1
                if count>1:
                    i.pop(m)
        nlistf.append(i)

    print(nlistf)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    string, k = input(), int(input())
    merge_the_tools(string, k)
```

Comment: don't use pop or del while traversing a list, it changes the length.

Comment: please format your code.

Comment: While you are fixing your post, also add the full traceback. It contains far more useful information than you believe.

Comment: It would help to explain what the code is *supposed to accomplish*.

Answer (score 0):

As another commentor said, if you mutate the list while you are iterating over it, especially delete operations, you will typically encounter index errors.

To avoid this, try iterating over the list backwards, using either:

`reverse(list)`

or

`for i in range(len(list), 0, -1):`